# using grep in a If statement to get all items, ignoring spaces

Tags: linux, bash

This is part of a homework problem in a beginning bash class.
I need to bring in the passwd file, which I have done with my passfile variable, then I need to be able to extract certain pieces of it and display the different fields.  When I manually grep from CLI using this statement below it works fine.  I'm wanting all the variables and I get them all.

```
grep 1000 passfile | cut -c1-
```

However, when I do this from the script it stops or breaks or starts over at the first 'blank space' in the users full name.  John D. Doe will return 3 lines when I only want one. I see this by echoing the value of i and the following.

```
for i in `grep 1000 ${passfile} | cut -c1-

user=`echo $1 | cut -d : -f1`
userID=`echo $1 | cut -d : -f3`
```

For example, if the line reads

```
jdoe:x:123:1000:John D Doe:/home/jdoe:/bin/bash
```

I get the following:

```
i = jdoe:x:123:1000:John
```

which gives me:
User is jdoe, UID is 509

but then in the next line i starts at R.
i = R. so User is R., UID is R.

next line

```
i = Johnson:/home/jjohnson:/bin/bash
```

which returns User is Johnson, UID is /bin/bash

The passwd file holds many users so I need to use the for loop to process them all.  I think if I can get it to ignore the space I can get it.  But not knowing a whole lot about linux, I'm not sure if I'm even going down the right path.  Thanks in Advance for guidence/help.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `cut` splits on spaces, not colons.  If you continue to use it, specify the separator.

You probably want to use `IFS=:` and a `read` statement in a `while` loop to get the values in:

```
while IFS=: read user password uid gid comment home shell
do
    ...whatever...
done < /etc/passwd
```

Or you can pipe the output of `grep` into the `while` loop.

Comment: @knittl: yes, it does - and it uses the same delimiter on input and output.  Sometimes, it would be convenient if it would handle an i-delimiter on input and produce an o-delimiter on output.  AFAIK, it doesn't.  You also face issues of spaces in fields.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use any external program? If so, I'd recommend **`awk`**

```
UID=1000
awkcmd="\$4==\"$UID\" {print \"user:\",\$1}"
cat $PASSWORDFILE | awk -F ":" "$awkcmd"
```

Comment: why the need to create a variable like awkcmd? And there's no need for cat. Here is the one line of awk: `awk -vuid=$UID '$4==uid{print "user: "$1}' file`

Comment: just to make it more understandable. i think. when OP is more familiar with awk, he can then do the cool one-liners :-)

Answer (score 0):

when parsing structured files with specific field delimiters such as passwd file, the appropriate tool for the job is awk.

```
UID=1000
awk -vuid="$UID" '$4==uid{print "user: "$1}' /etc/passwd
```

you do not have to use grep or cut or anything else. ( Of course, you can also use pure bash while read loops as demonstrated.)